# Can someone explain this perl snippet?

Tags: perl

```
for my $n (1, 2) {
  sub_example();
}

sub sub_example {
  my $bar = 1 if 1 == 2;
  if ($bar) {
     print "hahha, you see\n";
  }
  else {
     $bar = 1;
  }
}
```

So my question is why is $bar defined in the second loop iteration?

Comment: second loop? there is only one loop in your code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're taking advantage of a strange bug ([officially deprecated](https://metacpan.org/pod/perldeprecation#Using-my()-in-false-conditional.) and slated to become a fatal error in 5.30), which involves declaring a lexical (`my`) variable in a statement with a statement-modifier conditional which is false.

The reason that this happens is because `my $bar = 1;` basically has *two* functions. It has a compile-time function, which is to reserve space in the lexical pad for a variable, and to associate `$bar` with that space; and it has a run-time function, which is to assign `1` to `$bar` whenever control flow reaches the `my` statement (a statement like `my $foo;` without the assignment also has these two effects, except it assigns `undef` at runtime).

When you govern the statement with a false conditional like `my $bar = 1 if 1 == 2;`, the *compile-time* function stays exactly the same, but the *run-time* function is prevented from running using the false condition, which means that whatever value was in that storage is re-used, without being assigned fresh each time the code reaches that point. This gives an effect almost, but not exactly, like using a `state` variable. It's a cool trick, but not recommended for any serious use, and as I've mentioned, it will be fatalized in an upcoming release of perl, which is another reason not to rely on it.

Comment: *"reserve space in the lexical pad for a variable, and to associate $bar with that space"* I'm  sure you're very proud of your knowledge, but this language is neither necessary nor useful. Writing "Declare `$bar`" might actually help the OP.

Comment: @Borodin "Declare `$bar`" is something a programmer does, not a computer. Saying that declaring `$bar` declares `$bar` leaves no one any wiser. And saying "I'm sure you're very proud of your knowledge" is an offense against human decency publishable by revocation of internet privileges for no less than 60 days in civilized parts of the world.

Comment: More to the point, when you get into "weird behavior" territory, you can't afford to be fuzzy about the difference between names and storage, or the difference between scope and duration.

Comment: `my $bar = 1;` has *three* functions, and the one you didn't mention is why the construct is invalid. The three functions are: 1) Compile-time: Declare the var. 2) Runtime: cause the var to be cleared on exit. 3) Runtime: Assignment.

Comment: I found something:
perldoc perlsyn
[ SNIP ]
    NOTE: The behaviour of a "my" statement modified with a statement
    modifier conditional or loop construct (e.g. "my $x if ...") is
    undefined.  The value of the "my" variable may be "undef", any
    previously assigned value, or possibly anything else.  Don’t rely on
    it.  Future versions of perl might do something different from the
    version of perl you try it out on.  Here be dragons.

Answer (score 6):

You should never use `my` with a statement modifier. The behaviour of such constructs is **undefined** (see [perlsyn](http://p3rl.org/perlsyn)).

The current implementation doesn't clear the value assigned to the variable in the previous run of the subroutine, but there's no guarantee the behaviour will stay (in fact, it won't: see [perldeprecation](http://p3rl.org/perldeprecation)).

Comment: Not executing the `my` causes the var not to get cleared on exit.

Comment: Is this in the context of `my $bar; $bar = 1 if 1 == 2` ?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle: I don't understand your question. By separating `my` by a semicolon, the variable will be cleared on scope exit, and the assignment will be optimized away during compilation.

Comment: I was wondering if declaring the my variable first then setting a value for it with a conditional changes the behavior. When i ran it, the bug no longer happened. I didn't know if that was just luck (unpredictable as documented) or if it indeed prevents the bug.